# Why is the toggle button overlapping the NavigationViewItems on NavigationView

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, uwp

I am creating an UWP App and want to use the NavigationView as described in [this Walkthrough](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/navigationview). I've added a single NavigationViewItem to the MenuItems collection and an AutoSuggestBox to the NavigationView and the toggle button seems to be way to low in the layout, overlapping the first item. What is causing this behaviour?

[image: overlapping]

XAML:

```
<Page
x:Class="XXX.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:SituationPro"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:appmodel="using:Windows.ApplicationModel"
mc:Ignorable="d">


<NavigationView
    x:Name="NavView"
    ItemInvoked="NavView_ItemInvoked"
    SelectionChanged="NavView_SelectionChanged"
    Loaded="NavView_Loaded">

    <NavigationView.MenuItems>
        <NavigationViewItem Content="Map" Tag="map" Foreground="White">
            <NavigationViewItem.Icon>
                <FontIcon Glyph="&#xE707;"/>
            </NavigationViewItem.Icon>
        </NavigationViewItem>
    </NavigationView.MenuItems>

    <NavigationView.AutoSuggestBox>
        <AutoSuggestBox x:Name="GlobalSearchBox" QueryIcon="Find" Foreground="White" />
    </NavigationView.AutoSuggestBox>

    <Frame x:Name="ContentFrame" Margin="24">
        <Frame.ContentTransitions>
            <TransitionCollection>
                <NavigationThemeTransition/>
            </TransitionCollection>
        </Frame.ContentTransitions>
    </Frame>
</NavigationView>
</Page>
```

Bonus Question: Why is the AcrylicBrush that i added to App.xml not creating an Acrylic effect? It clearly colors the NavigationView Blue but no transparency can be seen whatsoever:

```
<Application
x:Class="XXX.App"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:SituationPro"
RequestedTheme="Light">

<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <AcrylicBrush x:Key="NavigationViewDefaultPaneBackground" BackgroundSource="Backdrop" TintColor="#120a8f" TintOpacity=".6" />
        <AcrylicBrush x:Key="NavigationViewExpandedPaneBackground" BackgroundSource="HostBackdrop" TintColor="#120a8f" TintOpacity=".6" />
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Comment: I am not being able to reproduce any of your issues. 

Everything works perfectly fine with the sample you provided. :/

Comment: I will try to create a new empty solution and start over, thanks for your time!

Comment: @JonasKöritz Have you solved your issue? If not, please tell the OS version and project's target platform.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue while running on Win 10 Insider build 17074, but the project UWP was targeting Windows 10 Fall Creators Update Build 16299. 
Switching the Target version to build 17083 in Project properties solved the issue. 
I also have the 17083 SDK installed, but I'm not sure if that's required.